# destructor for an array of pointers pointing to objects with a pointer member

Tags: c++, pointers, destructor

I have an array of pointers to an object. The object itself has a pointer member.

1. When I write a destructor the array of pointers does it also destruct the member pointer?
2. Is it safe to loop through a range for loop in destructor as objects getting deleted instead of an old style for loop?

Heres the class with array of pointer to objects.

```
class Graph {
    EdgeNode* edges[MAX_VERTICES] = { nullptr };    
public:
    Graph() {};
    ~Graph() {
        for (EdgeNode* edge : edges) { //Is it safe to loop like this versus a foor loop as objects getting deleted?
            delete edge;//Does it also delete the edge->next ???
        }
    }
```

};

Heres the class whose array is maintained in the Graph class above

```
#include <iostream>

const int MAX_VERTICES = 1000;
class EdgeNode { //Do I need a destructor here to ensure the next is getting deleted?
    EdgeNode* next{ nullptr };  
public: 
    EdgeNode() : next(nullptr) {}
    EdgeNode(EdgeNode* _next) : next(_next) {}
    EdgeNode* getNext() const { return next; }; 
};
```

Comment: `delete edge` "delete" the object pointed to by `edge`, which will call its destructor. It's up to that destructor to clean up (e.g. delete objects). The `delete` operator itself doesn't know anything about the object. It's not recursive.

Comment: And range `for` is "safe". It's actually implemented as an iterator loop.

Comment: I would suggest not adding a destructor to `EdgeNode` that deletes an `EdgeNode`.  Let `Graph` handle the deletion.  Also, `EdgeNode` has no idea where the `next` pointer comes from.  What if for some reason you want to create a linked list all on the stack, and not in the heap?  Then `next` would not be pointing to dynamically allocated memory.